# How to interpret lsmeans output for my lmer model?

Tags: r, interpretation, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I've defined an `lmer` model in R with 2 fixed effects, 2 random intercepts and a random slope:

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(value~A*B+(1+B|C)+(1|subject), data=Data, contrasts="contr.sum")
```

I want to look at a specific contrast in this model and I do this with lsmeans:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(fit4, pairwise~A*B, adjust="none")
```

The output is the following:

```
"Note: method with signature ‘sparseMatrix#ANY’ chosen for function ‘kronecker’,
 target signature ‘dgCMatrix#ngCMatrix’.
 "ANY#sparseMatrix" would also be valid

$lsmeans
 A   B        lsmean           SE   df    lower.CL  upper.CL
 0   1       0.2393981 0.1124053 4.99 -0.04969705 0.5284933
 1   1       0.3732209 0.0996028 3.11  0.06263727 0.6838045
 0   2       0.8311742 0.2919955 3.21 -0.06423808 1.7265865
 1   2       0.8496071 0.2873785 3.01 -0.06246008 1.7616743
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast     estimate         SE      df t.ratio p.value
 0,1 - 1,1 -0.13382277 0.06793821 2031.01  -1.970  0.0490
 0,1 - 0,2 -0.59177608 0.22618263    3.56  -2.616  0.0665
 0,1 - 1,2 -0.61020902 0.22454139    3.46  -2.718  0.0623
 1,1 - 0,2 -0.45795331 0.22445396    3.46  -2.040  0.1218
 1,1 - 1,2 -0.47638625 0.21723303    3.04  -2.193  0.1149
 0,2 - 1,2 -0.01843293 0.06789371 2028.96  -0.271  0.7860
```

I'm interested in contrasts 0,1-1,1 and contrast 0,2-1,2

So I would report the following:

> There is a significant difference in condition A1: condition B1: M=0.24, 95%confidence interval=[-0.05, 0.53]; condition B2: M=0.37, 95%CI=[0.06, 0.68], t(2031.01)=-1.97, p=.049. There is no significant difference in condition A2: p=.79.

This seems incorrect though (if I look at the confidence intervals).
What am I doing wrong / is there a better way to compute the contrasts?

Comment: Use the right tool for the job: The t tests of comparisons are the correct way to do comparisons, and the CIs are not, especially in light of the extremely high correlations among them (as evidenced by what happens to the d.f.). Also, if you're only interested in comparing A at each level of B, specify `pairwise~A|B` in the lsmeans call and you'll get clearer output.

Comment: Thanks. That helps ! 
One final question about this: would I be able to compute cohen's d effect size on the basis of the information I just received. I know it's difficult/impossible to compute effect sizes for lmer analyses. But in this case: maybe I could use lsmean / (SE x sqrt(N)) ?

Comment: Maybe somebody else can advise. I doubt that what you propose is right.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more sure I am that multiplying by sqrt(N) is wrong. You need to use the actual SD of the response as a reference, and in a mixed mode, that'd be a sum of variance components, square-rooted. In your model especially, it is an especially complicated animal because of the random slope.